# Input a name for mysql table when working with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am making a project using mysql connector with python. I am creating a function in which I want to create a table with a name inputted by user through python. But it is not working.

Source code I am using is this:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using picture instead of code,and also please provide full code of your content

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using slash(/) in the column name. You may change Maths/Hindi to maths_hindi
and Biology/Computer_science to biology_computer_science, you can use slashes in column comment.

Comment: Thanks.. I have done these changes while working on it again.. But I wanted to ask about inputting name for mysql table..